# Understanding the output of a pyomo model, number of solutions is zero?

Tags: output, solver, pyomo

I am using this code to create a solve a simple problem:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.core.expr.numeric_expr import LinearExpression

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.nVars = pyo.Param(initialize=4)
model.N = pyo.RangeSet(model.nVars)
model.x = pyo.Var(model.N, within=pyo.Binary)

model.coefs = [1, 1, 3, 4]

model.linexp = LinearExpression(constant=0,
                                linear_coefs=model.coefs,
                                linear_vars=[model.x[i] for i in model.N])
def caprule(m):
    return m.linexp <= 50
model.capme = pyo.Constraint(rule=caprule)

model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr = model.linexp, sense = maximize)

results = SolverFactory('glpk', executable='/usr/bin/glpsol').solve(model)
results.write()
```

And this is the output:

```
# ==========================================================
# = Solver Results                                         =
# ==========================================================
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Problem Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: 50.0
  Upper bound: 50.0
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 2
  Number of variables: 5
  Number of nonzeros: 5
  Sense: maximize
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Solver Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  Termination condition: optimal
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 0
      Number of created subproblems: 0
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.09727835655212402
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Solution Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0
```

It says the number of solutions is 0, and yet it does solve the problem:

```
print(list(model.x[i]() for i in model.N))
```

Will output this:

```
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Which is a correct answer to the problem. what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface between `pyomo` and `glpk` sometimes (always?) seems to return  0 for the number of solutions.  I'm assuming there is some issue with the generalized interface between the pyomo core module and the various solvers that it interfaces with.  When I use `glpk` and `cbc` solvers on this, it reports the number of solutions as zero.  Perhaps those solvers don't fill that data element in the generalized interface.  Somebody w/ more experience in the data glob returned from the solver may know precisely.  That said, the **main thing** to look at is the termination condition, which I've found to be always accurate.  It reports optimal.

I suspect that you have some mixed code from another model in your example.  When I fix a typo or two (you missed the `pyo` prefix on a few things), it solves fine and gives the correct objective value as 9.  I'm not sure where 50 came from in your output.

##### (slightly cleaned up) Code:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.core.expr.numeric_expr import LinearExpression

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.nVars = pyo.Param(initialize=4)
model.N = pyo.RangeSet(model.nVars)
model.x = pyo.Var(model.N, within=pyo.Binary)

model.coefs = [1, 1, 3, 4]

model.linexp = LinearExpression(constant=0,
                                linear_coefs=model.coefs,
                                linear_vars=[model.x[i] for i in model.N])
def caprule(m):
    return m.linexp <= 50
model.capme = pyo.Constraint(rule=caprule)

model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr = model.linexp, sense = pyo.maximize)

solver = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk') #, executable='/usr/bin/glpsol').solve(model)
results = solver.solve(model)

print(results)

model.obj.pprint()
model.obj.display()
```

##### Output:

```
Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: 9.0
  Upper bound: 9.0
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 2
  Number of variables: 5
  Number of nonzeros: 5
  Sense: maximize
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  Termination condition: optimal
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 0
      Number of created subproblems: 0
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.00797891616821289
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0

obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
    Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
    None :   True : maximize : x[1] + x[2] + 3*x[3] + 4*x[4]
obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
    Key  : Active : Value
    None :   True :   9.0
```